# How to listen a socket in Tomcat(servlet container)?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, sockets

I have to let an web application to listen a socket(*ServerSocket*), and handle the socket stream.

But the application is just deployed in Tomcat which is just a servlet container, it doesn't have JCA support. And establishing a server socket in servlet thread is unreasonable.

solution 1:

The ugly solution is to write a **standalone java application** to listen socket, then communicate with web server. but it is not a sound solution.

solution 2:

I wrote a **ServletContextListener** which starts to listen socket when contextInitialized(), once receiving a socket, it will be handed by a thread. That means a thread pool is located in ServletContext. Of course, I destroy the thread pool when contextDestroyed.

What do you think about the solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "standalone Java application" can be as good executed from inside a `ServletContextListener`. You can manage a threadpool using [`ExecutorService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Comment: then just add the implemened ServerContextListener to web.xml using the <listener> tag. :D